# CakePHP 3: Arrange element files inside the View Template folder

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In some projects, I wish (and I do) that the elements are inside the View Template folder. This applies in particular to elements that are not used across the board.

As far as I know, there is no way to set the element folder at runtime, or better yet to add one more.

I manage so far that I write an additional template folder to the configuration:

**inside the Apps Controllers initialize:**

```
configure::write("App.paths.templates", array_reverse(array_merge(configure::read("App.paths.templates"), [APP . 'Template' . DS . $this->request->controller . DS])));
```

It works well, but is that the way to go? Will this work in the future with new Cake releases?

Comment: It looks like you want to be able to put elements for People (for example) into `src/Template/People`. Is that right? You know you can do that and just use `$this->element('People/xyz')`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, but if I use 

`$this->element ("Peoples / xyz") `

the template file will be searched under 

`./src/Template/Element/Peoples/xyz`

, not under 

`./src/Templates/Peoples/Eleemnt/xyz.`

Comment: (sorry, Template, not Templates; but i can edit comments only 5min...

Comment: While there are very often ways to bend Cake to your will in such areas, I've found that it's generally better to go its way than spend hours debugging code to jump through hoops just to satisfy my personal preferences.